# Unable to log in to RabbitMQ's web management interface on Kubernetes

Tags: authentication, kubernetes, rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm

I am having issues logging in to RabbitMQ through its web management interface when using a custom username and password.

I have an empty [microk8s](https://microk8s.io/) based kubernetes environment and I try to install RabbitMQ like so:

1. Install while setting the username and the password:

```
helm install rabbitmq bitnami/rabbitmq --version 6.27.1 --set auth.username=yolo123,auth.password=prettypig_012
```

2. All good, wait for the pod to go online.
3. Forward ports to be able to access the management interface:

```
kubectl port-forward rabbitmq-0 5672 15672
```

4. Access the management through `localhost:15672`
5. Enter `yolo123` and `prettypig_012` as username/password.
6. **Login failed** message appears and the user cannot log in.

Are my expectations about logging in wrong here?

Note that I am able to log-in with user user and the auto-generated password in the secret resource created with RabbitMQ installation.

**RabbitMQ version**

```
Helm chart: 6.27.1
Application: 3.8.3
```

**Helm version**

```
version.BuildInfo{Version:"v3.2.3", GitCommit:"8f832046e258e2cb800894579b1b3b50c2d83492", GitTreeState:"clean", GoVersion:"go1.13.12"}
```

**kubectl version**

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.4-1+6f17be3f1fd54a", GitCommit:"6f17be3f1fd54a88681869d1cf8bedd5a2174504", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-23T21:16:24Z", GoVersion:"go1.14.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"18+", GitVersion:"v1.18.4-1+6f17be3f1fd54a", GitCommit:"6f17be3f1fd54a88681869d1cf8bedd5a2174504", GitTreeState:"clean", BuildDate:"2020-06-23T21:17:52Z", GoVersion:"go1.14.4", Compiler:"gc", Platform:"linux/amd64"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As seen in [this commit](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/commit/43e70827ef73560e118907b3a2c0d7d9c72bce52#diff-b81c5c74c5c6f200d8ad669085b8af0fR6), `auth.username` and `auth.password` should be used with Chart version `7.x.x`.

For [`6.27.1 version`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/c56fdc45ca6c10d1a44a75a71ca7e26597470833/bitnami/rabbitmq) use `rabbitmq.username` and `rabbitmq.password`